# other models analogue of the ''five aggregates''

Tags: five-skandas

what are the other models analogue of the ''five aggregates'' USED BY THE BUDDHA, and their references in the sutas used by the buddha that mentioned at the end of this video.
[YouTube] The Five Aggregates Part 2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Oo0ad9Ptf-w#t=924

there is form and the the mind is:

feeling

perception

mental formation

conciousness of senses

but what are the other models for this ?

Answer (score 0):

One = Life, Dukka, Samsara,

Two = Body and Mind, namarupa and vinnana,

five = 5 aggregate  (Skanda),

Twelve = 12 faculties,

Eighteen = 18 Dhathu,